# Problems with xpath in htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, xpath, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I have the following html:

```
<span class="stArrow"><span class="stButton_gradient stHBubble" style="display: inline-block;"><span class="stBubble_hcount">4</span></span></span>
```

For fetching the text with htmlagilitypack i used the xpath:

```
//span[@class='stArrow']//span[@class='stButton_gradient']//span[@class='stBubble_hcount']
```

But No values are picked up. From rigorous testing I found out that the xpath may be faulty. Can anyone point out to the fault here?

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
//span[@class='stArrow']//span[@class='stBubble_hcount']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer...tried it...still doesn't work...by the way, do we face problems if try to fetch facebook likes or say tweets?

Comment: @aceBox show us the code..if you are parsing facebook or twitter pages,you can instead use their API's instead

Comment: Follow this link : http://www.indianexpress.com/news/liability-clause-stalls-deal-on-2-new-nreactors-in-kudankulam/1184975/                     I am trying to fetch the tweets/likes in this page.

Comment: @aceBox `//span[@class='st_twitter_hcount']//span[@class='stBubble_hcount']` should work

Comment: Doesn't work...did you try it yourself...because then, something else is faulty

Comment: @aceBox How are you getting the source HTML? Download in code? I suspect the twitter tags are not available at all since they're loaded in different request by ajax/javascript.

Comment: @Fung I am using htmlagilitypack for establishing connection to a webpage, and then trying to fetch the number of tweets using xpath...but yes eve I thing that it is getting generated programatically, because of which I am not able to fetch them...Have tried all possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
//span[@class='stArrow']/span[contains(@class, 'stButton_gradient')]/span[@class='stBubble_hcount']/text()
```